# What is (or where can I find) the electrostatic potential inside a vertically split cylinder of finite length?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I want to find the potential (and eventually electric field) inside a cylinder of radius, $r$, which has been vertically split, with each half being held at equal and opposite potential, $\pm V$, and is of finite length.

The only textbook solution I can find is for the infinitely long case:

$$\Phi(\rho, \theta) = \frac{4 V}{\pi} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2 n + 1} \left( \frac{\rho}{r}\right)^{2n + 1} \cos(2 n \theta + \theta)$$

which is from *Riley and Hobson's Mathematical Methods For Physics And Engineering*.

As a further addendum, I wonder if there is a book/list/paper or any source which has potentials or Laplacian solutions to various geometries. This would be helpful to verify or quickly look up potentials of different geometries.